# makefile giving unexpected end of file error

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

```
HOMEDIR = $(shell pwd)
DEFAULT = 4.0.3
YESDIR = $(shell echo $(@:install-%=%) | tr A-Z a-z)
NODIR = $(shell echo $(@:clean-%=%) | tr A-Z a-z)
install:
@$(MAKE) install-$(DEFAULT)   
install-%:
@cd $(HOMEDIR);\
if [ ! -e $(YESDIR) ]; then \
  echo "Library $(@:install-%=%) Version=$(YESDIR) does not exist"; \
elif [ -e $(YESDIR)/Install.sh ]; then \
    echo "Installing $(PKGNAM) version=$(YESDIR)" ; \
    cd $(YESDIR) ;\
    $(SHELL) Install.sh $(HOMEDIR) 1 ;\   
elif [ -e $(YESDIR)/Makefile ]; then \
    cd $(YESDIR); \
    $(MAKE); \
else \
    echo "Installation instruction for $(@:install-%=%) Version=$(YESDIR) does not exist"; \
fi;
```

the above makefile gives me the following error
line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Your makefile isn't indented properly ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove trailing blanks in this line:

```
    $(SHELL) Install.sh $(HOMEDIR) 1 ;\
```

Comment: Nice catch `++`